# After erasing an item with localStorage.removeItem, is there any js tool to shorten the length?

Tags: javascript

I mean after:

```
localStorage.removeItem('x');      //erasing the item with key 'x'
localStorage.getItem('x');      //i get 'null' as the new value of the key 'x'
```

is there any `js` tool that will completely disappear the `x` key out of the localStorage, so if localStorage.length was for example 15, then after I remove the item it becomes 14, and there are no `null` values stored?

Sorry if I did not asked the question in the best way, I am as new to this as it gets.

Comment: Once item is removed there should not be a key `"x"` defined at `localStorage` object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I am getting it. So I got 'null' because there was no such key uh?

Comment: _"So I got 'null' because there was no such key uh?"_ Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use the `getItem` method.
`null` is a mistaken return e.g.: *wrong return value* (for non existing keys) introduced by fellas invading JavaScript from static procedural languages who don't understand JavaScript at all.

In order to avoid confusion, please use the canonical `localStorage[key]` call so to get `undefined`return, or to make sure the key doesn't exist 
make use of the most powerful JS `in` operator as : `"x" in localStorage > true/false`

Comment: no I mean that you are getting a browser JS-bug  return - which is not your fault - but simply a wrongly assigned return value for the function method.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate a little more and let you know. Sorry I changed my first comment, I did it before I saw your reply.

Comment: Well Bekim, my problem was to think about localStorage as an array, because I was storing an array. Here is my solution:    for (var i=erasedValue; i<lengthOfTheLocalStorage; i++){
     var nextItem = localStorage.getItem(i+1);
     localStorage.setItem(i, nextItem);
    }

Comment: So I do not use localStorage.removeItem, I move every value one position. Thank you for your answer!! :)